# How to write a multi-arity function (variable number of arguments) in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I've been breaking my head trying to write a multi-arity function on the lines of [`Development.Shake.cmd`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.19/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:cmd), but even after 8 different attempts across 3 days, I have failed to get this to compile.

Here's what I've managed to get done:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules #-}

--
-- this is for an i18n system integrated with Lucid
-- where I want the `t_` function to work with a variable number of arguments
--

module Try4 where

import Lucid (HtmlT, div_, toHtmlRaw)
import Control.Monad.Trans (lift)
import Data.Text as T

default (Text)


newtype Translation = Translation { rawTranslation :: Text }

class (Monad m) => HasI18n m where
  fetchTranslation :: Text -> m Translation

class (HasI18n m) => InterpolationValue m a where
  -- the reason why this function is not pure, is because it is possible
  -- for the conversion function to depend on the monadic context. For example,
  -- it is not necessary that date/time values are always converted to text using
  -- the same format. The format to be used could be part of the monadic context.
  interpolationVal :: a -> m Text

class Interpolate arg result where
  t_ :: arg -> result

instance (HasI18n m, a ~ ()) => Interpolate Text (HtmlT m a) where
  t_ k = do
    x <- lift $ fetchTranslation k
    toHtmlRaw $ rawTranslation x

instance (HasI18n m, InterpolationValue m v, a ~ ()) => (Interpolate Text ((Text, v) -> HtmlT m a)) where
  t_ k (i, v) = do
    x <- lift $ fetchTranslation k
    val <- lift $ interpolationVal v
    toHtmlRaw $ applySingleInterpolation (rawTranslation x) (i, val)

instance (HasI18n m) => InterpolationValue m Text where
  interpolationVal = pure

instance (HasI18n m) => InterpolationValue m Int where
  interpolationVal = pure . T.pack . show

applySingleInterpolation :: Text -> (Text, Text) -> Text
applySingleInterpolation memo (k, v) = T.replace ("%{" <> k <> "}") v memo

myHtml :: (HasI18n m) => HtmlT m ()
myHtml = div_ $ do
  div_ $ t_ "some.i18n.key"
  div_ $ t_ "some.18n.key" ("interpolation1", "some-string")
```

**And finally, here's where I'm stuck.** How do I write the (recursive) type-class instance to get the following to compile? No matter what I try, I cannot get the `m` of `InterpolationValue m a` and `HtmlT m a` to unify. Somehow, because of the `Interpolate arg result`, GHC seems to get confused and infers a different `m1` and `m2`.

```hs
t_ "some.18n.key" 
   ("interpoliation1", "some-string") 
   ("interpolation2", 10 :: Int)
   ("interpolation3", fromGregorian 2020 1 1)
```

Comment: This question would be clearer with some explanation of what `t_` is supposed to do. Is the following correct: `t_` takes a key as its first argument, with which to look up some interpolation string, and the following arguments (any number) are substitutions (as key-value pairs) which get applied to the interpolation string?

Comment: As a first guess, try `class Interpolate arg result | result -> arg`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia that is correct. `fetchTranslation` will return something like `Hello %{name}` where `name` is an interpolated variable who's value will be provided as such: `t_ "customer_greeting" ("name", customerName)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest starting from copying [Text.Printf](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Text.Printf.html) and incrementally modifying it til you get what you want. That's the pure source from which the Shake version was copied. The important instances are:

```
instance (PrintfArg a, PrintfType r) => PrintfType (a -> r) where
instance (a ~ ()) => PrintfType (IO a) where
```

That's one inductive instance, and one terminal instance.